# XML parsing python nested

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have the following XML file:

```
<annotations count="1">
  <track id="0" label="Machine">
    <box frame="0" ><attribute id="8">act1</attribute></box>
    <box frame="1" ><attribute id="8">act2</attribute></box>
    <box frame="2" ><attribute id="8">act1</attribute></box>
  </track>
</annotations>
```

I want to extract the frame and the action inside attribute. For example i would like to have (frame: 0 , act1), (frame: 1 , act2)
... 
Right now what I am doing is

```
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(xml_file_path).getroot()

for track in root.iter('track'):
  for box in track.iter('box'):
    frame = box.get('frame')
```

How can I obtain also the corresponding attribute ( act1, ..., act 1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `<attribute id="8">act1</attribute>` with

```
box.find('attribute')
```

To get the act you use:

```
>>>box.find('attribute').text
act1 # or act2
```

The python docs are a very good resource: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: I tried that also before but what i get is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' . I don't understand why

Comment: Ok the problem was that one of the lines didn't have the attribute .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array notation which could be useful if you are scraping or putting it in a massive loop

`root[0][0][0].text`

`root[0][0][1].text`
and so on